# Identifying https encryption type used in ASP.NET Web API DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, middleware

I'm currently expanding the logging part of my ASP.NET Web API application but I'm having trouble identifying what encryption scheme is being used. As this logging is done through a `DelegatingHandler` I only have access to the `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` given to me through the middleware chain.

How do I Identify the https encryption type (SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.3 etc..) used in a ASP.NET Web API `DelegatingHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking about whether the request is https or just http. If that's what you're looking for you just need `httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.Scheme`.

However it sounds like you're looking for more information about the certificate itself. Information about the SSL certificate isn't really a property of the individual request and can't be accessed from `HttpRequestMessage` or `HttpResponseMessage` as far as I'm aware. It's more a property of the application and machine configuration.

If you wanted to get information about the SSL certificate you could do something like this:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumbprint", true);
var certificate = certificateCollection[0];
var version = certificate.Version;
var signatureAlgorithm = certificate.SignatureAlgorithm;
```

Obviously that's just one way to do it and there's more error handling you would want to do. The general idea is you probably have access to the certificate thumbprint used by the application through the `app.config`. If you use that you can look up the certificate information from `X509Store` as I did above. Then you'll have access to all kinds of properties.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm looking at whether the request is encrypted with SSL 2.0, TLS 1.0, TLS1.3, etc..